# How to store Clients in a list

Tags: java, sockets, networking, arraylist, network-programming

I am running a server, and I have an arraylist of type Client 
When a client connects through 
    ServerSocket.accept()
I pass the new Socket to the arraylists constructor. This is everything inside the constructor

```
this.add(new Client(Socket client));
```

My problem is when a client disconnects, it closes the Socket, but it doesn't delete its spot in the arraylist, and shift everything down one. So the arraylist is constantly growing bigger.

What can I do/use to fix this problem?

Sometimes I will run commands that will execute on all clients which is why I store the clients in an arraylist.

Is there a better alternative for storing clients in a server?

**Update 1**

The classes are in the beginning stages. Very little has been implemented. So far the HashMap option suggested in the answer works best for me. Thank you for your replies

Comment: You should check if the client is still connected to the server. If not, then use `java.util.ArrayList.remove(Object)` Method to remove the client from the ArrayList.

Comment: When the client disconnects do you have the `Client` object you want to remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem.

You should use hash map here .. Add the client with object as value and use some key. Whenever you disconnect it, remove it from the map.

A good question could me what should be the key? may be the object reference (depends on your choice) or anything that is unique with respect to client object (there must be something, if not, you can generate it easily).

```
Map<Integer,Client> clientMap = new HashMap<Integer,Client>();
```

Comment: Well it is a game, maybe I could use the players ID?

Comment: @Loligans Yes, you could. Or the `Client` instance you're having there.

Comment: what so ever, since hash map keeps the key so you can shrink and increase it easily.. it is all about the selection of data structure ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the Client from the ArrayList, the rest elements in the list will automatically shuffle upwards along the list.

```
//java.util.ArrayList.remove(Object) shifts any subsequent elements
// to the left (subtracts one from their indices).
```

Say,if the Client is Client A and the ArrayList is ArrayListA, then you should apply

```
ArrayListA.remove(ClientA);
```

But, the ***better approach*** would be to use HashMap to store client information as mentioned in Danyal Sandeelo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If Client it's your own class, then you can try this one:

```
public class Client {

public final List<Client> clients;

public Client(List<Client> clients, Socket socketClient) {
    this.clients = clients;
    clients.add(this);
}

public void disconnect() {
    clients.remove(this);
}}



   List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
    new Client(clients, new Socket());
    new Client(clients, new Socket());
    new Client(clients, new Socket());
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of assumptions are made, for example I'm assuming you have a `disconnect()` method in your `Client` class. Please provide more details if you want a more accurate solution.

One way of doing it could be by passing a callback to your client so it removes itself from the `ArrayList` when it's done. Very rough implementation:

```
public class Callback {
    private ArrayList<Client> clients;

    public Callback(ArrayList<Client> clients) {
        this.clients = clients;
    }

    public void remove(Client client) {
        clients.remove(client);
    }
}
```

Then pass the `Callback` when you instantiate the `Client`:

```
Callback callback = new Callback(list);
list.add(new Client(socket, callback));
```

Then call the `remove()` method of the callback. If the `Client` has a `disconnect()` method, then inside it you can do

```
public void disconnect() {
    // bla bla
    callback.remove(this);
}
```

This way the `Client` can clean up after itself when it needs to :)

Comment: The classes are in the beginning stages of being implemented. I am open to anything that makes sense. How do professional servers hold clients?